# Jenkins cannot find file even though it exist in the workplace Selenium File not found: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError)

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver

So I am seeing this below, the file exist and this is the ruby line of code thats supposed to run:

```
upload = @browser.file_field(:type => 'file', :class => 'react-fine-uploader-file-input')
    upload.send_keys("workplace/uploads/test1.mp3")
    @browser.button(:class => 'change-file-button').wait_until_present
```

`Jenkins` error below in the console output:

> File not found: workplace/uploads/test1.mp3
>   (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError)

Comment: Can you check the complete path of the upload file. Jenkins have \workspace\ as the repo. so check the logs for the complete path.

Comment: i did already it still didnt work